# Biblatex Q: Single entry for multiple data fields?

Tags: biblatex

So I have a biblatex entry:

```
@book{sterne,
  title={The Life and Opinions of Tristram Shandy, Gentleman},
  author={Sterne, Laurence},
  editor={Ross, Ian Campbell},
  introduction={Ross, Ian Campbell},
  annotator={Ross, Ian Campbell},
  year={2009},
  publisher={Oxford University Press}
        }
```

Notice that the editor, annotator and introduction fields are all identical.

Is there a way to concatenate these 3 entries into a single entry *à la:*

```
{editor,introduction,annotator}={Ross, Ian Campbell},
```

Note that I'm just starting out using this stuff for bibliographies.

Comment: To say it short: no.

Comment: But note that you will get it concatenated in the _output_, where this can be rendered something like "Laurence Sterne. The Life and Opinions of Tristram Shandy, Gentleman. Ed. and annot., with an introd., by Ian Campbell Ross. Oxford University Press, 2009."

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for the entry fields is given. In "section 2.2 Entry Fields" in the `biblatex` documentation (type `texdoc biblatex` in your terminal/console) you can read what is possible.  There is no possibility to "sum up" several entry field names to one or something else.

So the answer to your question can only be: **No, it is not possible**.

BTW: In your editor you you can easy copy the fist written name into the other fields, I think there will never such a syntax ...

Edit:  As @pst said in his comment:

> please note that you will get it concatenated in the **output**, where
>   this can be rendered something like "Laurence Sterne. The Life and
>   Opinions of Tristram Shandy, Gentleman. Ed. and annot., with an
>   introd., by Ian Campbell Ross. Oxford University Press, 2009."

Just test this simple MWE (packages `filecontent` is only used to have code and bib file in one compilable code):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{sterne,
  title={The Life and Opinions of Tristram Shandy, Gentleman},
  author={Sterne, Laurence},
  editor={Ross, Ian Campbell},
  introduction={Ross, Ian Campbell},
  annotator={Ross, Ian Campbell},
  year={2009},
  publisher={Oxford University Press},
} 
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[%
  backend=bibtex8, % biber bibtex8 bibtex
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Some text \cite{sterne} and more text.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And see the output:

[image]